# Cannot enable select into/bulkcopy on SQL Server 2005 database using sp_dboption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlbulkcopy, database-permissions

I am trying to enable the select into/bulkcopy database option on a SQL Server 2005 database using the command:

```
EXEC sp_dboption 'mydbname', 'select into/bulkcopy', 'true'
```

After executing the above, running `EXEC sp_dboption 'mydbname', 'select into/bulkcopy'` tells me that the option is still set to OFF.

I've confirmed that my Windows login is a user in the database and that it belongs to the db_owner role. Having read the [MSDN Documentation for sp_dboption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187310%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), this appears to be the only prerequisite for using the procedure to change options on a database.

Are there any other steps or settings I am missing that could prevent me from being able to enable this option?

Comment: That procedure is deprecated anyway. What about `ALTER DATABASE [mydbname] SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED WITH NO_WAIT`

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That procedure is deprecated. You can use

```
 ALTER DATABASE [mydbname] SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED WITH NO_WAIT
```

This seems to happen if your DB is currently in `SIMPLE` recovery model.

Looking at the `sp_dboption` procedure definition the relevant bit of code is

```
    if @alt_optvalue = 'ON'
    begin
        if databaseproperty(@dbname, 'IsTrunclog') = 1
            select @alt_optvalue = 'RECMODEL_70BACKCOMP'
        else
            select @alt_optvalue = 'BULK_LOGGED'
    end
```

The effect of running `ALTER DATABASE [mydbname] SET RECOVERY RECMODEL_70BACKCOMP WITH NO_WAIT` seems to be to set the recovery model to `SIMPLE` so basically it has no effect in this instance